# Is there any way putting dropdown in gojs panel?

Tags: javascript, gojs

Is there any way we can integrate HTML controls like dropdown in goJS panel. I can see we can have text box inside panel and checkboxes as well. But i can't find dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to add arbitrary HTML to a GoJS panel, but you could fashion elements to work like a drop-down.

It may be better to bring up HTML elements when you click on a node, which might suit you. The [custom context menu sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/customContextMenu.html) does that (but with right click context menus).

Another example of showing HTML elements over a Diagram is the [data visualization sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/dataVisualization.html), though this works on mouseOver instead of click, the idea should be similar.

Comment: Ya but that would be an alternate way. I am thinking to directly add dropdown in the panel. Thanks for the detail answer.